# How can I change web page's font using Chrome dev console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm am looking for the easiest way to view a web page in a different font.
I managed to do this through Chrome dev tools, but my method was messy.
Is there any line I can simply paste into the console to achieve this?
The site does use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the font family for the body to Comic Sans:

```
    let newStyle = document.createElement('style');
    newStyle.innerHTML = 'body { font-family: "Comic Sans MS"}'
    document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

If other elements on the page (h1, etc.) have font family assigned to them, you will need to add those element names after "body" (body, h1, ...).